# How can i disable the submit function after finishing the textfield

Tags: forms, ajax

i wrote a textfield and a submit button with ajax method.
The code is belowed:

```
$form['response']=array(
            '#type'=>'textfield',
            '#size'=>40,
            '#maxlength'=>255,
            '#name'=>$slogannid->nid,
            );


            $form['send_response']=array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#name'=>$slogannid->nid,
            '#value'=>t('Send'),
            '#ajax'=>array(
              'callback'=>'send_response_callback_function',//which will receive a form and form_state as arguments,and return a renderable array
              'wrapper'=>'attach_the_new_comment_'.$slogannid->nid,//The css id of the area to be replaced by the content returned by the #ajax['callback']
              'effect'=>'fade',
              'speed'=>'fast',
              'method'=>'append',
              'event'=>'click',
               ),
            );
```

My problem is the ajax submit button work. However, when i finished the textfield and press the enter. The form will be sent and refresh the page.

How can i disable the enter event when i finished the textfield?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Hide Submit module? http://drupal.org/project/hide_submit

Comment: thx for answer, but i doesn't want to hide submit button. I just want to disable the enter key.

Comment: Not sure if you read the features list, it allows the option to disable it and not just hide it.